# Change button name when the button is clicked

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, frontend

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
import 'package:paylater/res/asset_strings.dart';
import 'package:paylater/res/motito_colors.dart';
import 'package:paylater/res/string_en.dart';
import 'package:paylater/res/style.dart';
import 'package:paylater/screens/motito_stepper.dart';
import 'package:paylater/screens/reset_password_verify.dart';
import 'package:paylater/util/validator.dart';
import 'package:paylater/widget/motito_dialog.dart';
import 'package:paylater/widget/motito_flat_button.dart';


class Resetsteps extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_ResetstepsState createState() => _ResetstepsState();
 }

 class _ResetstepsState extends State<Resetsteps> {
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
 final _phoneController = TextEditingController();


 bool phoneFieldEmpty = true;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  MotitoDialog md = MotitoDialog(
  context,
  isDismissible: false,
);
md.style(
  borderRadius: 8.0,
  messageTextStyle: CustomTextStyles.kBody.copyWith(
    color: MotitoColors.kNeutralsGrey4,
    fontSize: 14.0,
  ),
);
return MotitoStepper(
  step: 1,
  total: 3,
  leading: GestureDetector(onTap: () {}, child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.arrow_left),), 
  helpMessage: 'I need help on the forgot my password page',
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: FormBuilder(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 50.0),
          Text(
            'Forgot my Password',
            style: CustomTextStyles.kHeader3.copyWith(
              color: MotitoColors.kSecondaryTextColor1,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 2.0),
          Text(
            'Please type in your phone number and we will send you a 6 digit code',
            style: CustomTextStyles.kBody.copyWith(
              color: MotitoColors.kNeutralsGrey5,
              fontSize: 14.0,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 32.0),
                  textFieldLabel(
                    StringEn.kPhoneNumber,
                    required: true,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                    ],
                    controller: _phoneController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                    decoration: inputDecoration(
                      context,
                      hint: StringEn.kPhoneHint,
                      prefixText: '(+233)',
                    ),
                    onChanged: (phone) {
                      if (phone != null && phone.isNotEmpty) {
                        setState(() {
                          phoneFieldEmpty = false;
                        });
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          phoneFieldEmpty = true;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                      FormBuilderValidators.minLength(context, 9,
                          errorText: AssetStrings.kInvalidPhone),
                      FormBuilderValidators.maxLength(context, 10,
                          errorText: AssetStrings.kInvalidPhone),
                      Validator.leadingZeroValidator,
                    ]),
                  ),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0),
          SizedBox(height: 120.0),
```

I am a junior intern and was assigned a task to add a new feature on an existing app. I am all done with the UI but cant get a particular function on my code to work here is the code for the button and I want the text to change on the button to "Loading...".

What can I do to achieve that?

```
                         MotitoFlatButton(
                        label: StringEn.kContinue,
                        enabled: !phoneFieldEmpty,
                        onTap: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                            Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                           builder: (context) =>   ResetPasswordVerify()));
                          }
                        },
                      ),
          SizedBox(height: 56.0),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
 }
 }
```

Here is also the code for the button widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:paylater/res/motito_colors.dart';
import 'package:paylater/res/style.dart';

const _buttonRadius = 8.0;

class MotitoFlatButton extends StatelessWidget {
final String label;
final VoidCallback onTap;
final Color bg;
final Color textColor;
final Color disabledBg;
final Color disabledTextColor;
final double width;
final bool enabled;

const MotitoFlatButton({
@required this.label,
@required this.onTap,
this.bg = MotitoColors.kMotitoBlue,
this.textColor = Colors.white,
this.disabledBg = MotitoColors.kButtonDisabled,
this.disabledTextColor = MotitoColors.kButtonDisabledText,
this.width = double.infinity,
  this.enabled = true,
 });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Material(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(_buttonRadius),
   child: InkWell(
    onTap: enabled ? onTap : null,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(_buttonRadius),
    child: Ink(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      width: width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: enabled ? bg : disabledBg,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(_buttonRadius),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          label,
          style: CustomTextStyles.kBody
              .copyWith(color: enabled ? textColor : disabledTextColor),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  );
  }
 }
```

I have tried my best and can't get it to work.

Comment: Your explanatory text ("I am a junior intern...") appears to have been placed inside a block of code. Is this meant to be one piece of code, or is it two files?

Comment: its two files actually

Comment: OK, thanks. It appears the first file is missing a lot of closing indents, and the second file is missing a lot of opening indents. But people are answering, so perhaps this is clear enough for readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to make UI changes you have to call **setState**

> Calling setState notifies the framework that the internal state of
> this object has changed in a way that might impact the user interface
> in this subtree, which causes the framework to schedule a build for
> this State object

So in your particular case I would change that button to a **Statefull** widget (right click on Stateless and Refactor) and then on your onTap function you can just put:

```
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      setState(
        () {
          isLoading = true;
        },
      );
    },
    child: isLoading ? Text('Loading...') : Text('Click me'),
  ),
```

So now whenever you click your button it's state will change and your UI should be updated

Also you could put a loading indicator there instead of just text like this:

```
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      setState(
        () {
          isLoading = true;
        },
      );
    },
    child: isLoading
        ? Text('Loading...')
        : Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              strokeWidth: 2.0,
            ),
          ),
  ),
```

Comment: i Will try this as well and see

Comment: Do i make isLoading a setter??

Comment: You can just make your isLoading a boolean outside of your build method and set it to false

Comment: any tips on how to disable the button after state is changed?

Comment: @SEYRAMEMMANUELAGBANYO You could create another **isButtonWorking** bool that would be set to true but onTap of a button set it to false and disable the onPressed function just like you change your Text with **isLoading**

Comment: Done!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could try to wrap the Button with a GestureDetector and set the State of the String you give threw to the Button Widget with setState, this should work:

```
GestureDetector(
                            onTap:(){
                              setState(() {
                                yourString = "Loading..."
                              });
                            },
                          child: YourButton(yourstring),
                        )
```

Comment: there will be two onTaps in that block of code. Is that going to work? please look at the widget code as well

Comment: Try it. Or make a String variable for your label and on default it is "StringEn.kContinue" and then make in the onTap of your Button a setState where you change the variable to "Loading..."

Comment: i will try this

Comment: If it doesn't work, write it here